# JS/jQuery: Filter object properties by array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets have an example JS object (aka "associative array"):

```
var zoo = {
  monkey: { legs: 4, color: "black" },
  fish: { legs: 0, color: "yellow" },
  turtle: { legs: 4, color: "green" },
  emu: { legs: 2, color: "gray" },
};
```

Now I want to retrieve a nested object (aka "subarray") of aquatic animals. Is there a standard JS/jQuery construct or function to filter object properties by array ("index an array by array"), i.e. something like:

```
var aquatic = zoo["fish", "turtle"];
```

The result should obviously be `{ { legs: 0, color: "yellow" }, { legs: 4, color: "green" } }`.

Or is a `for` loop the simplest solution here?

Comment: _"associative JS array"_ === JS Object.

Comment: "_standard JS/jQuery construct"_... jQuery is not a language.

Comment: First its a JS Object. Second, you do not have subarrays. You have nested objects. Third, yes you can use `for..in` to loop over properties of an object

Comment: `var aquatic = ["fish", "turtle"].map(key => zoo[key])`

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I never said jQuery would be a language :-) And I know that "associative array" is actually an object. Anyway, for JS non-professionals like me, associative array is a more explicit term, that's why I used it. JS objects behave pretty much like associative arrays. But if my terminology offends you, I can surely edit the text. Just let me know.

Comment: @yman I am so offended! ;) -- Nah, I just prefer to be picky and ask that people use the standard terms for a language. Also JS objects may look like associative arrays, but they really aren't... at all.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Okay, hope it's better now.

Comment: @yman fret not! It is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map()` and return array of objects.

```js
var zoo = {
  monkey: { legs: 4, color: "black" },
  fish: { legs: 0, color: "yellow" },
  turtle: { legs: 4, color: "green" },
  emu: { legs: 2, color: "gray" },
};
var aquatic = ["fish", "turtle"];

var result = aquatic.map(e => zoo[e]);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Yay! An answer with no for loop!

Comment: @evolutionxbox: No `for` loop, but make no mistake, `.map` is still a loop.

Comment: @Cerbrus sure, but only in a recursive function sense.

Comment: You can see what `map()` is doing in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map `Polyfill`, it is using while loop.

Comment: @NenadVracar again sure, but it can also be written [without a for/do/while loop](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/reduce-composing-software-fe22f0c39a1d#8efd).

Comment: @evolutionxbox: `reduce` is also a loop. reduce and map aren't `recursive` functions. They're just methods on the array prototype. All semantics, but the more you know :-)

Comment: It can be using recursion, but if i am not mistaken in that link they are using reduce which is also using `while` loop `:)`

Comment: @NenadVracar: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Sure it's internally implemented as a kind of loop, I was just looking for a simpler code. Not expecting performance gain.

Comment: @NenadVracar Indeed it is. I had incorrectly assumed reduce was loop-less.